# SwiftUI Table (macOS 12) and CoreData

Tags: macos, core-data, swiftui, ios15

I have a problem with the sortOrder in Tables with FetchedResults as datasource. Currently I'm using XCode 13 beta, Deployment Target macOS 12.0. Here is my code:

```
struct MyTable: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Person.fetchRequest(), animation: .default) 
    var people: FetchedResults<Person>
  
    @State private var sortOrder = [KeyPathComparator(\Person.familyName)]
    @State private var selectedPersonID: Person.ID?
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(people, selection: $selectedPersonID, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
            
            TableColumn("Nachname", value: \.familyName)
            TableColumn("Vorname", value: \.givenName)
            TableColumn("Adresse", value:\.address)
            TableColumn("Telefon 1", value:\.phone1)
            TableColumn("Telefon 2", value:\.phone2)
        }
        .onChange(of: sortOrder) {
           // --> PROBLEM: how can I implement the sortOrder with NSSortDescriptor ? <--
        }
   
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I implement the sort functionality in the `.onChange`-Method? The first attempt using `people.sort(using: $0)` failed. I also tried to parse the `fetchedResults<Person> people` into an Array:

```
var peopleArray: [Person] {
     Array(people)
}
```

But then I get an immutable value `peopleArray` on which I cannot sort with the `.sort(using:)`-Method.

Thanks for any help!

Nico

Comment: what error do you get with `people.sort(using: $0)`

Comment: I get this error: ```Value of type 'FetchedResults<Person>' has no member 'sort'```.

Answer (score 1):

I know, the question is old, but perhaps there's someone looking for the answer.

```
@FetchRequest(
    fetchRequest: Person.fetchRequest(), 
    sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\. familyName, order: .forward)],
    animation: .default
) 
var people: FetchedResults<Person>

var body: some View {
    Table(people, selection: $selectedPersonID, sortOrder: $people.sortDescriptors) {
        TableColumn("Nachname", value: \.familyName)
        TableColumn("Vorname", value: \.givenName)
        TableColumn("Adresse", value:\.address)
        TableColumn("Telefon 1", value:\.phone1)
        TableColumn("Telefon 2", value:\.phone2)
    }
}
```